# Сбор UI. Как это происходит?

Tags: веб-программирование, ui, терминология

Недавно мне задали вопрос: "Умеешь ли собирать UI?". Услышав ответ нет, мне сказали обязательно выучить. Погуглил и ничего не нашёл. Подскажите как это делать и что это такое?

Comment: Это может много что означать. Правильнее было у них и спросить, что они под этим имеют в виду.